# django development static file confusion

Tags: django, static

I can't understand why the following is necessary :-

In urls I have,

```
    url(r'^static/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve',
    {'document_root': '/wamp/www/diary/static'})
```

In settings.py if I have,

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

The files are not retrieved, but if I change that to

```
STATIC_URL = '/xxx/'
```

then images files with '/static/img.jpg' are retrieved.

Answer (score 0):

so my idea;;

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

url and static_url;  using the **django.views.static.serve**.

```
def serve(request, path, document_root=None, show_indexes=False):
```

if you are using static_url is template tag

```
<img src="{{ STATIC_URL }}img/logo.png" />
```

or load static tag == {{ STATIC_URL }}:

```
{% load static %} 
<img src="{% static 'img/logo.png' %}" />
```

use url:

```
url(r'^static/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve',
{'document_root': '/wamp/www/diary/static'})
```

not template tag

```
<img src="/static/img/logo.png" />
```

hard path "/static/";

I think the only difference is the use of Template_tag django ; use Ngnix and apache config static files configuration..

Comment: Thank you for your response, but I don't think you answered the question which is why does django successfully deliver statis files when STATIC_URL is set to nonsense, but fails when set to '/static/'